# How to edit footer generated by spay fancy extension while installing spree 2.0.3

Tags: spree

I installed spree 2.0.3 and then I installed spree_fancy extension....
I want to edit the footer which was generated by spree_fancy extension
Spree generated following folder:
spree_api   spree_backend    spree_cmd
spree_core  spree_dash  spree_frontend  spree_sample

Can anyone know where the views are located which was generated by spree_fancy extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the footer located here:

https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/blob/1f12308a3562be2cde6c21467942ba07b7c3c536/app/views/spree/shared/_footer.html.erb

You can override the footer by placing a file in your application in the matching path:

```
app/views/spree/shared/_footer.html.erb
```

After creating that file and restarting your webserver, content will be read from that file instead of spree_fancy.

Another option is to use the Deface plugin:
https://github.com/spree/deface

You can use this to override portions of the content within the footer, and is more appropriate when making small changes.

You can learn more about both of these techniques by reading the spree customization guide:

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/view.html